# How to set constant width of strokes from PKInkingTool in PencilKit

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

When drawing on screen using finger/pencil with the PencilKit API, I would like to set the width of strokes to be a constant. Currently, the width setting in say `PKInkingTool` only sets the baseline width when drawing with finger or pencil, and the width varies if one does slow or fast strokes with their finger/pencil.

I'm not sure how to setup a minimum example, there is a lot of code to get a PencilKit View working. You can use [this example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/221/) from Apple to setup a simple drawing app.

Here's my code to choose a default tool for drawing:

```
canvas.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .white, width: 10)
```

where `canvas` is a `PKCanvasView` object. There is a `validWidthRange` property within each InkType ([link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkinkingtool/inktype)) but I'm unsure if this is what can help me achieve what I want.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @RoiMulia I have, hope my answer below is helpful to you too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a solution (thanks to [Will Bishop](https://twitter.com/WillRBishop)), however I'm not sure it's the best for everyone. I solve it by redrawing the stroke after its been completed with a constant width. Apple released new APIs for [`PKStroke`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkstroke) and [`PKStrokePoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkstrokepoint) at WWDC2020 for iOS 14. Here's the relevant section of my code (`newDrawing` is the new drawing with constant stroke width, while `canvasView` refers to the current drawing on my `PKCanvas`):

```
var newDrawingStrokes = [PKStroke]()
    for stroke in canvasView.drawing.strokes {
        var newPoints = [PKStrokePoint]()
        stroke.path.forEach { (point) in
        let newPoint = PKStrokePoint(location: point.location, 
                                     timeOffset: point.timeOffset, 
                                     size: CGSize(width: 5,height: 5), 
                                     opacity: CGFloat(1), force: point.force,
                                     azimuth: point.azimuth, altitude: point.altitude)
        newPoints.append(newPoint)
        }
        let newPath = PKStrokePath(controlPoints: newPoints, creationDate: Date())
        newDrawingStrokes.append(PKStroke(ink: PKInk(.pen, color: UIColor.white), path: newPath))
     }
let newDrawing = PKDrawing(strokes: newDrawingStrokes)
```

This is some preliminary code that I threw together, so if you find any bugs/mistakes do let me know!

Comment: Yes, PKStroke and PKStrokePoint are in the new Betas. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: where did you put that code? I tried putting inside canvasViewDidEndUsingTool delegate method, but then on the last line when I assign canvasView.drawing = newDrawing, it throws a warning and reverts my stroke. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Well I put it in the `canvasViewDrawingDidChange` delegate method, but that's specific to my use case. Regarding your error, I'm not sure you can reassign the canvas drawing like that - I use `newDrawing` for some background processing, but I don't change the canvas drawing display itself.

Comment: Ahh I see :( I wanted to modify the drawing on the cavas itself and when using canvasViewDrawingDidChange, it'd trigger a recursion. I'll probably have to use a custom solution instead of PencilKit. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to make it fixed via swizzling `UITouch` `force` and `timestamp` methods.

You can add this Objective-C category in your project:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITouch (UITouch_Overrides)

+ (void)load {
    [super load];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self swizzleForce];
        [self swizzleTimestamp];
    });
}

+ (void)swizzleForce {
    [self swizzle:@selector(force) with:@selector(ed_force)];
}

+ (void)swizzleTimestamp {
    [self swizzle:@selector(timestamp) with:@selector(ed_timestamp)];
}

+ (void)swizzle:(SEL)originalSelector with:(SEL)swizzledSelector {
    Class class = [self class];
    
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);
    BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
            originalSelector,
            method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
            method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod(class,
            swizzledSelector,
            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}

- (CGFloat)ed_force {
    return 1.0;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)ed_timestamp {
    return 0;
}

@end
```

Comment: The load function is called only once per app launch and I am unable to change the width to original PKInkingTool style dynamically later. How can i switch between constant width and default PKInkingTool behaviour dynamically based on a constant variable from swift?